# Embedded pig in Java

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am  trying to Run Embedded Pig in Java. My pig version is 0.15 and my Hadoop version is 2.7.1. 
By default Embedded pig runs in Hadoop 0.20 version in apache pig site i read that to make pig use my own Hadoop version,i need to set HADOOP_HOME.
I have set the HADOOP_HOME in my bashrc file and in Eclipse Classpath variables also.

I am getting the following error

```
hadoop20.PigJobControl: falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)
```

Comment: can you add the complete stacktrace? Its difficult to understand what the issue is as per the current form of the question.

Comment: Oneliner error is not enough to debug. Please be more specific and add the entire error stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Got my problem resolved by setting HADOOP_HOME In the environment variables of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my Question by setting HADOOP_HOME property in the Classpath which is in Run Configurations of Eclipse.

To Run Embedded pig we need to set HADOOP_HOME property so that pig come to know which version of Hadoop you are using by default it will take Hadoop 0.20 version.

To set HADOOP_HOME in eclipse,

```
Run Configurations-->ClassPath-->User Entries-->Advanced-->Add ClassPath Variables-->New-->Name(HADOOP_HOME)-->Path(You Hadoop directory path)
```